# Hide or remove website content with query string?

Tags: url, parameters, query-string

A news website, newswebsite.com/xnews.php, lists a bunch of news articles one after the other. I don't like news articles from the website fakenews.com. Is there a way to make newswebsite.com/xnews.php hide entries from fakenews.com with a query string? I imagine it would look something like https://www.newswebsite.com/xnews.php/?hide=fakenews.com

I tried the above string, which obviously didn't work, and which was akin to my pretending to speak a foreign language that I do not know. Go ahead, try it for yourself. I also tried searching for how to do it but the information about forming queries and parameters was not thorough.